# When does first win of the day bonus reset?

Tags: starcraft-2

At what time does the daily bonus reset?
[image: Screenshot of Zerg Victory screen showing a "First Zerg Win Of The Day Bonus" of +25.000 XP (European notation, equal to 25,000 in the US)]

I am personally mostly interested in EU region's reset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Information from the Beta and around the net would seem to indicate that the First Win of the day does not have a daily reset time (a la World of Warcraft Daily Quests), but rather a rolling timer, 22 hours after your previous win (a la World of Warcraft Transmutation timers).

Unfortunately, there is not yet a way to track how close you are to the counter expiring and becoming eligible again

Comment: Just 22?  Not 24?

Comment: @MatthewRead Yes. It gives the user a bit of legroom, since if it's exactly 24 hours, the timer has a tendency to get later and later with each cycle (since the user must wait until the timer expires to earn that day's bonus). League of Legends does something similar.

Comment: That's awesome, wish more games did that!

Comment: 2 Years have passed, is there any new information on the timers ? Coop seems to have a similar timer but i can´t find sources.