# Is there a way to tell if I already got my First Win of the Day bonus?

Tags: overwatch

Each day (I don't know when it resets), one can earn a +1500 XP First Win of the Day bonus in Overwatch. Pro-tip: You can get this quickly by playing vs. easy AI. Sometimes, I forget if I already got it.

Is there an easy way to tell aside from completing another match to see if I get the bonus?

Comment: It may be the same system used in SC2. Similar Question was asked there: [Link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108528/when-does-first-win-of-the-day-bonus-reset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to see in-game if the bonus was already awarded.

However, if you're aware of the exact day roll-over time, you can estimate if you already played or not a game that day. The day resets at midnight UTC, so feel free to convert to your timezone.

Comment: Do you have a source for your time? i couldn´t find one.

Comment: Well, source is myself, since I see it reset everytime at 9PM and I'm at -3 UTC

Comment: Resets at 1AM for me, and I'm BST (currently UTC+1), so that checks out. I'd expect it to reset at 12AM once the clocks roll back though.

Answer (score -1):

The bar for EXP gain after each match does show the EXP breakdown one by one. Pay attention to it every time you win a match. The reset timing for the first win is dependent on the region, so I am not too sure about that.

Comment: Yes it shows there, but the question is if you can see it without playing another round.

Comment: I don't think they added in this feature yet